# How do I make existing tags show up in the categorization tab when editing a Dexterity content type?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I've enabled the Dublin Core metadata behavior for a content type I'm developing using Dexterity 1.0.1 and Plone 4.1. Here's the XML from my content type XML file:

```
<property name="behaviors">
  <element value="plone.app.dexterity.behaviors.metadata.IDublinCore"/>
  <element value="plone.app.content.interfaces.INameFromTitle"/>
  <element value="collective.flowplayer.behaviors.IFlowplayerFile"/>
  <element value="plone.app.versioningbehavior.behaviors.IVersionable" />
</property>
```

This successfully displays a Categorization tab in the Edit form. Users can enter new tags into the multi-line textbox. However, unlike when I edit standard Plone content types, there's no list of checkboxes for existing tags in the system. Does Dexterity support this and if so how do I enable it for my content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue filed in the Dexterity Issue Tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/dexterity/issues/detail?id=158

So I assume Dexterity doesn't support this behavior yet.